# How to comprehend a sentence with multiple contrasting word and commas?

Tags: commas, conjunctions, contractions

> Darwin’s influence on modern scientific inquiry is largely ......; **yet while** Darwin’s ideas inform fields as disparate as genetics and social psychology, one **cannot help but** think that each group, in ...............Darwin’s ideas, has imparted a slant that might have surprised Darwin.

Blank 1

(A) anecdotal
(B) commonplace
(C) uncontested

Blank 2

(D) subverting
(E) appropriating
(F) questioning

Explanation:

> "Darwin’s influence on modern scientific inquiry is largely ......;"

Up to here we don't have any idea either it accepted or ignored

> **yet while** Darwin’s ideas inform fields as **disparate** as genetics and social psychology,

Here two contrast are, which inform that the blank-1 should be in accord with above line.

> one cannot help but think that each group, in ...............Darwin’s ideas, has imparted a slant that might have surprised Darwin.

I could not comprehend what would be the option for second blank.

Answer (score 2):

We can work forwards from ABC to DEF by knowing the history of biology, but that uses more than English usage. So let's work backwards, starting with DEF.  No one will be surprised by the "slant" (i.e., a particular biased view) of an opponent of one's position.  A surprising interpretation may arise from a supporter, though. This leaves out (D) *subverting* (which means to undermine) and (F) *questioning* (which indicates a refusal to accept). That leaves the answer (E) *appropriating* (which means adopts as one's own). So social psychologists and geneticists endorse Darwinian theories but with changes that would surprise their originator.

Now the blank in ABC has to be filled in with a word that in a general scientific sense ("largely") agrees with the particular endorsements (i.e., "appropriations) of those in specific fields of study. The only word that fits such a description is (C) *uncontested*.

So scientists in general accept Darwin's theories (since these are uncontested), but scientists in specific fields accept them in particular ways (i.e., appropriate them) in ways that might surprise Darwin.